Discord: ошибка PrivilegedIntentsRequired
Написал простой код
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = '*****'
PREFIX = '!'
intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("и тебе привет")
    await ctx.send("хаха")

bot.run (TOKEN)

вроде, всё хорошо, но когда запускаю, пишет:
[2024-06-02 16:00:43] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Huawei\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1312\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot.run (TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Huawei\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Huawei\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Huawei\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 778, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Huawei\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 704, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос


discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting
privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the
developer portal. It is recommended to go to
https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the
privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not
possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.

Думаю, вам стоит прочитать о чём эта ошибка, ведь в ней всё написано
